# Load URL into parent keep child

Tags: php, forms, hyperlink

I want to make this code load new URL in parent and open child page as it does now...how can i accomplish this?

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post" target="foo" onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=1040,height=900,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish? Does your code already work?

Comment: Not sure if onSubmit would open the window quick enough for the target to work, maybe jQuery to open a window and then submit data?

Comment: @Hope4You what i want is when the login form is filled in to open the page in a new window (currently works) and have the parent page to load a page thats says lets say success! (not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post" target="foo" onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=1040,height=900,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'); document.location='http://google.com/'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put Javascript code in the child window, triggered by onLoad (but it's not necessary), that will set window.opener.location.href to point somewhere else.

When you POST the form, the form result will open in a new window, and that window .opener property should be set to the parent (the page where the input form is still displayed). Then the child page will be able to know its parent.

You might try to bind submit to a function which will open the new window AND refresh current page, but I've had mixed (and browser-dependent) results with that [Edit: my results might well be obsolete]